# imacros como extrair apenas numeros

Tags: asp.net-web-api

eu tenho este codigo

```
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=D:\ FILE=media.jpg WAIT=YES

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ID:adcopy-puzzle-image-image 

CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT

TAB OPEN

TAB T=2

URL GOTO=http://2captcha.com/imacros.html

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://rucaptcha.com/in.php ATTR=NAME:key 

CONTENT=edaceeb357f4b0

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION: aqui fica o mesmo link de cima ATTR=NAME:file 

CONTENT=D:\media.jpg

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=TYPE:submit&&VALUE:recognize

WAIT SECONDS=1

SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

TAB CLOSE

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:adcopy_response CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}``
```

mas quando chega na hora de extrair preciso só dos números, exemplo aparece na tela `OK |958959`, nisto o `iMacro` copia tudo ai da erro queria que copia-se somente os números 
oque tenho que fazer no código.

Comment: desculpe se não fico muito organizado e muito complicado de mexer na hora de postar

Comment: @Zignd iMacro usa uma linguagem propria de script, acho que não é web-api nao.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe adicionei web-api seguindo o conceito desse artigo no wikipédia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API mas talvez fosse interessante adicionar uma tag própria para ele, era só para remover a web-api-2 mesmo, que estava sendo utilizada indevidamente